# R h2o: examining the nodes on a deeplearning neuralnet model

Tags: r, deep-learning, h2o

I would like to be able to examine the node structure on my neural networks. Specifically, I use L1 and L2 regularisation and would like to know what proportion of my weights have atrophied to zero. Does my trained neuralnet use every single node, or can I get away with using much fewer hidden nodes? That sort of thing.

Here's a toy problem:

```
library(h2o)
h2o.init()

x <-seq(-10,10,by=0.0002)
y <- dnorm(x,sd=2)*sin(2*x)     # The function the neuralnet will attempt to fit
plot(x,y,type="l")

df <- data.frame(x=x,y=y)
df2 <- as.h2o(df)
model <- h2o.deeplearning(df2,
                x=1,
                y=2,
                hidden=c(200,100,50,10,5),  # way more hidden nodes than it needs
                l1=0.0000001,           # regularisation to reduce the number of unnecessary nodes
                l2=0.0000001,
                activation="Tanh",
                export_weights_and_biases=TRUE)

P <- as.data.frame(h2o.predict(model,df2))

lines(x,P$predict,col=2)
legend("topleft",legend=c("Training data","nn output"),col=c(1,2),lwd=1)
```

[image: training vs ground truth]

**Is there a function within h2o that will give me the information on what all the weights are?**

(I've tried h2o.weights(), it only appears to give me the first layer)

**Failing that, given that the model is a S4 object, what are the ways of inspecting an S4 object?**

**Bonus question: Is there any ability within h2o for visualising the node structure?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`h2o.weights()`](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-r/docs/reference/h2o.weights.html) function returns the first layer weights by default, as an H2OFrame.  You can get an arbitrary layer by changing the `matrix_id` argument.

Some examples:

```
> h2o.weights(model)
           x
1  0.3520632
2  0.5535296
3 -0.4793063
4  0.3828013
5 -0.3253765
6  0.7234487

[200 rows x 1 column]


> h2o.weights(model, matrix_id = 5)
          C1        C2         C3         C4         C5         C6          C7          C8         C9         C10
1  0.7233770 0.7793967 -1.4486042 -0.8187707  0.8667952  1.0290394  0.26213858  0.02487412  0.3342296  0.39383927
2  0.4528885 0.2434976  0.5963052  0.9640941 -0.4480562 -0.1976745 -0.63002998  0.17428128 -0.9241131  0.13199258
3 -0.5477357 0.4918589 -0.7991062 -0.6445754  0.3618000  0.1324274  0.60856968 -0.35876906 -0.0655041  0.21673690
4 -0.3147219 0.2541574 -0.5886489 -0.9993418  0.3042635  0.4107490 -0.08639368 -1.11863077  0.8755589 -0.06117416
5 -0.7028044 0.4625969 -0.3838535 -0.6484048 -0.6975272  0.2663548 -0.17953268  0.14127040 -0.6482394 -0.04426440



> hidden <- c(200,100,50,10,5)
> for (i in 1:(length(hidden) + 1)) {
+   print(dim(h2o.weights(model, matrix_id = i)))
+ }
[1] 200   1
[1] 100 200
[1]  50 100
[1] 10 50
[1]  5 10
[1] 1 5
```